# Typescript: Full import of module cannot find type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tree-shaking

**Context**

I'm using design framework named Carbon and this package includes `@carbon/icons-react`, but it is not tree shaked at all. It means that when I use single icon, it imports all the icons. The size of all icons is nearly 2MB so it causes performance/network issue. Therefore, I decided solve this issue by full path import of specific icon.

**Problem**

Icon package: `@carbon/icons-react`
Icon package type: `@types/carbon__icons-react`

Original import code: `import { Search } from '@carbon/icons-react` ---> IMPORT ALL ICONS!
**Improved import code: `import Search from '@carbon/icons-react/es/search/16` ---> CANNOT INFER TYPE!**

How can I solve this typing issue? Can I specify or declare type for specific path?

Comment: I suspect by importing the icon using method 1 imports all icons. Check with webpack analyzer. Do you have a custom build process or using CRA?

Comment: What you said is in my question... I already checked it imports all icons. I'm using CRA, I think it's not problem of webpack. Probably, problem of library. And I can solve this issue if full path import can infer type for that icon

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other way. Is it importing all icons with method 1? I'm using the method 1 to import but not using ts. All looks good and does not import all icons

Comment: Did you analyze your bundle size? Umm... pretty strange... WHAT IS MY PROBLEM..sad story..

Comment: Yes, for me it was importing all the icons when analyzed and then I realized it's not the issue with icons import, it was the issue how I was importing one of carbon component UIShell. I was importing like   `import SwitcherItem from 'carbon-components-react/UIShell/lib/SwitcherItem` instead of `import {SwitherItem} from 'carbon-components-react`

Comment: I suggest you to look the code for imports with "lib"

Comment: I tried, but when I use `import Content from 'carbon-components-react/lib/components/UIShell/Content`, it still has other code like DatePicker, etc. Is it normal?